# Unable to display image retrieved from jason in Angular

Tags: angular-material

[error while looping with in template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRs03.png)  I have a problem displaying an image from json. **Please suggest to me how can I display an image  retrieved from json.** Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Apologies for asking basic question but I'm unable to figure out my mistake. I've tried this setting with out success.

```
[src]= ""
```

**Json file**

```
{
  "products": [{
      "pId": 1,
      "name": "jacket",
      "price": "400Rs",
      "image": "img_chania.jpg"
    },
    {
      "pId": 2,
      "name": "shirts",
      "price": "500Rs",
      "image": "https://assets.myntassets.com/h_1440,q_90,w_1080/v1/assets/images/1376577/2016/9/15/11473928353466-Roadster-Men-Black-Regular-Fit-Checked-Casual-Shirt-4501473928353310-1.
    }
  ]
}
```

**Html file**

```
<div>
  <li *ngFor="let product of products ">
    <img [src]="product.image | json">
  </li>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.httpClient.get < products[] > ('assets/products.json').subscribe(data => {
    this.products = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(this.products);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<img [src]="product.image">` json pipe is not needed in image source.

And also no need to stringify your response.
check if you are getting response as intended.

```
this.httpClient.get<products[]>('assets/products.json').subscribe(data => {
 console.log(data);
 this.products = data;
 console.log(this.products);
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: Hi @Manoj
 
Thanks I tried that <img [src]="product.image"> but I am not able to display the image 
whereas I am getting the required console output

Comment: where as in template when I am trying for loop *ngFor="let product of products
I am getting error as :- 
Error: Error trying to diff '{"products":[{"pId":1,"name":"jacket","price":"400Rs","image":"img_chania.jpg"},{"pId":2,"name":"shirts","price":"500Rs","image":"https://assets.myntassets.com/h_1440,q_90,w_1080/v1/assets/images/1376577/2016/9/15/11473928353466-Roadster-Men-Black-Regular-Fit-Checked-Casual-Shirt-4501473928353310-1.jpg"}]}'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed 
Please let me know how to fix this :(

Comment: It seems your response is different to what your code is expecting. try "this.products = data.products;"

Comment: Hi Manoj 
can you help me out what wrong I have done  
Although it seems to be pretty simply one but tried out the same 
still unable to display :(

Comment: here is simple version of what you are looking for https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-visvesvaraya-0b587?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Rajat - I have tried and replicated your scenario in the following github link which is a  stackblitz project. Please find the link to my project which seems to solve your issue.

https://github.com/akashkriplani/Angular-9---Fetch-data-from-JSON-file

Three things that you were doing wrong:

1. There is no need to stringify your response using `JSON.stringify()`.
2. The data which you receive on subscription should be assigned to this.products as: 
   `this.products = data.products` or you can loop over the list items like I have done in the above mentioned link
3. Also, bonus points if you use elvis operator `(?.)` in your html file in the image tag:

   `<img [src]="products?.image">`

There is no need to use json pipe in the html file since the image source is of type string

I hope this resolves all your queries.